# Moving the bones breaks/tears the mesh?

Tags: rigging, rigify

When I rotate the bones it actually tears my mesh like this ,
[image]
what should I do to prevent this. This is my first day of rigging and I am using rigify plugin and Blender 3.0.0.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: hello, are you sure that the vertices are connected?

Comment: @moonboots I downloaded a model from the web to to learn rigging , so I don't really know.

Comment: @moonboots no the vertices are not linked as in edit mode when I selected some vertices and clicked L , only a small area was selected , the whole model had many vertices that are not linked. How can I join the complete model?

Comment: it really depend on the topology, you can try to merge the vertices : Select all and press M (and play with the threshold in the Operator box on the bottom left), but I'm not sure it will give a good result